# Normal approximation for Negative Binomial regression

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, regression-coefficients, count-data

In negative binomial regression, the distribution is specified in terms of its mean, $\frac{pr}{1-p}$, which is then related to explanatory variables as in linear regression or other Generalized linear models.  From the expression for the mean `m`, one can derive $\frac{m}{m+r}$ and $1-p=\frac{r}{m+r}$.  Then, substituting these expressions in to real-valued `r`, yields this parametrization of the probability mass function in terms of `m`:

$$
    \Pr(X = k) = \frac{\Gamma(r+k)}{k! \, \Gamma(r)} \left(\frac{m}{r+m}\right)^k \left(\frac{r}{r+m}\right)^r \quad\text{for }k = 0, 1, 2, \dotsc
  $$
The variance can then be written as $\frac{m^2}{r}$.
More info on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_formulations

Now consider this example:

```
require(MASS)
# generate data
set.seed(123)
N <- 1000
phi <- 1
b0 <- -0.5
b1 <- 0.4
x <- seq(1, 10, length.out = N)
y <- rnbinom(N, size = phi, mu = exp(b0 + x * b1))
```

I now do a negative binomial regression:

```
> glm.nb(y ~ x)

Call:  glm.nb(formula = y ~ x, init.theta = 1.04541122, link = log)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    -0.4958       0.3940  

Degrees of Freedom: 999 Total (i.e. Null);  998 Residual
Null Deviance:      1963 
Residual Deviance: 1115     AIC: 5609
```

I now use the same data with a Gaussian linear model:

```
> glm(y ~ x)

Call:  glm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     -7.160        2.869  

Degrees of Freedom: 999 Total (i.e. Null);  998 Residual
Null Deviance:      235200 
Residual Deviance: 179500   AIC: 8034
```

when I predict from both models, the predictions are very similar.

However, I do not understand how the coefficients in both models are related. How do I have to transform the coefficients from the NB model so that it yields the coefficients from the Gaussian model (and vice versa).

thanks.

Comment: Do you understand what the part where you typed "link=log" means? (Note that this question really has almost nothing to do with normal approximation; a more accurate title would be useful)

Comment: @Glen_b I know that there is a log link in the NB model and it surely must play a role, but which one? And what title would be better?

Comment: The main issue is the difference between the effect of the identity link in the linear regression and the default log link in `glm.nb` (i.e. how the mean is modelled), rather than the distribution around the mean (whose major impact will relate to how the variance is modelled if the counts are not small).

Comment: @Glen_b so the transition of the parameter estimates cannot be done?